# How can I extend a function so that it is diagonalizable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $V$ be a vector space so that $W<V$ and $B$ a basis in $W$. If $f$ is and endomorphism in $W$, based on the matrix attached to the function $f$, how can I extend the function to two endomorphisms in $V$ -one diagonalizable and one not-.

My thought was to add a Jordan block after properly extending the matrix and the basis, so then it is non-diagonalizable. On the other hand, to make it diagonalizable adding a lambda eigenvalue while the matrix remains diagonal would do.
How would you guys approach this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you know about $f$?

Comment: If $f$ is not diagonalisable on $W$, there is no way to extend it to a diagonalisable linear map on $V$.

Comment: okay yeah, should’ve said that f is diagonalizable in w

Comment: So what you said is fine so long as $\dim V\ge\dim W+2$. What if $\dim V=\dim W+1$?

Comment: does that problem hold too if the "new" eigenvalue is a -1 or a 1? trying to see what the logic behind it is. also, in the exercise i found this problem dimW=3 and  V=R^4

Comment: @uberupense When you say "diagonalizable" in this context, since you're working over $\Bbb R$, do you necessarily mean diagonalizable with real eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is convenient to come up with a complementary subspace $U$. That is, we can guarantee that there exists a subspace $U$ such that $V$ is the (internal) direct sum $V = W \oplus U$, and I will refer to such a subspace $U$ going forward. The specifics of how this complementary subspace might be constructed are not important for our purposes here.

With that established: as you said in your comment, we know that $f:W \to W$ is diagonalizable. In order to extend this to a diagonalizable map over $V$, it suffices to define the extension $\tilde f: V \to V$ such that $U$ is also an invariant subspace of $W$ and $\tilde f|_{U}$  is diagonalizable. For instance, the map $\tilde f$ defined by
$$
\tilde f(w + u) = f(w) + u \quad \text{for all }w \in W, u \in U
$$
is diagonalizable. In this case, the restriction $\tilde f|_U = \text{id}_U$ is diagonalizable.

If $\dim(U) \geq 2$, then the approach that you seem to have in mind works perfectly well: if $U$ is an invariant subspace of $\tilde f$ such that $\tilde f|_U$ is non-diagonalizable, then $\tilde f$ is non-diagonalizable. However, if $\dim(U) = 1$, the all endomorphisms of $U$ are diagonalizable, so this approach is ruled out.

For the case where $\dim(U) = 1$, the following construction would work: let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $f$. Let $u_*,w_*$ denote elements of $U$ and $W$ respectively, with $u_* \neq 0$ and $w_*\notin \text{Ran}(f - \lambda \text{id}_W)$. Notably, $U = \{tu_* : t \in \Bbb C\}$. Define $\tilde f$ by
$$
\tilde f(w + tu_*) = f(w) + tw_* + \lambda t u_*, \quad \text{for all }w \in W,  t\in \Bbb C.
$$
To see that this map is not diagonalizable, show that $\text{Ran}(\tilde f - \lambda \,\text{id}) \supsetneq \text{Ran}[(\tilde f - \lambda \,\text{id})^2]$.

---

An illustrative example for constructing the non-diagonalizable extension: suppose that within $\Bbb R^4$,
$$
W = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4): x_4 = 0\}.
$$
Suppose that relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$. Suppose that the matrix of $f:W \to W$ is given by $[f]_{\mathcal B} = A \in \Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$.

The matrix of $\tilde f$ relative to the standard basis $\mathcal S$ of $\Bbb R^4$ (i.e. $\mathcal B$ with the vector $(0,0,0,1)$ added) must be of the form
$$
M = [\tilde f]_{\mathcal S} = \pmatrix{A & v\\0 & \lambda}
$$
for some scalar $\lambda$ and some vector $v \in \Bbb R^3$. Now, $M$ will be diagonalizable if and only if $(M - \lambda I)$ and $(M - \lambda I)^2$ have the same rank. With that in mind, note that
$$
(M - \lambda I)^2 = \pmatrix{A - \lambda I & v\\0 & 0}^2 = \pmatrix{(A - \lambda I)^2 & (A - \lambda I)v\\0 & 0}.
$$
Because $A$ is diagonalizable, $(A - \lambda I)$ and $(A - \lambda I)^2$ will have the same range. So, $M$ will fail to be diagonalizable if and only if $v \notin \text{range}(A - \lambda I)$.

To be more specific, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3}.
$$
Of course, we find that
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\
0&0&3&1\\
0&0&0&3}
$$
is not diagonalizable. However, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\
0&0&3&1\\
0&0&0&2}, \quad \pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\
0&0&3&1\\
0&0&0&1}
$$
are diagonalizable, even though $1$ and $2$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Could you please explain that one last paragraph as if I was having quite a lot of difficulties? I kinda got lost from hereon: w∗∉Ran(f−λidW). Also, if dimU=1, if the "new" eigenvalue was the same as one already in f, why does my approach of adding a Jordan block not work? (As in a 2x2 Jordan Block with the new repeated eigenvalue). ps.:I am actually working in R.

Comment: @uberupense To your second question: if you're adding a whole $2 \times 2$ Jordan Block on the diagonal, then you're making the matrix 2 rows and columns bigger. For your case of $V = \Bbb R^4$, if $W$ is the $x_4 = 0$ subspace (so that $f$ corresponds to the upper-left $3 \times 3$ submatrix of the $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$ of $\tilde f$), then maintaining the way $f$ is defined on $W$ requires that the bottom row of $M$ has 3 leading zeros and the only entries we can modify are those of the final column; that's not enough room to fit a $2 \times 2$ Jordan block into.

Comment: @uberupense By the way: for other subspaces $W$, the correspondence between the matrix corresponding to $f$ and the matrix corresponding to $\tilde f$ is more complicated

Comment: I meant adding a Jordan Block as in making the matrix 4x4 and then having the added row-column be all zeros except for a3,4 and a4,4, which are respectively 1 and lambda (the eigenvalue in a3,3. That would make up a 2x2 Jordan Block, so sorry for the confusion

Comment: @uberupense That would work, assuming that entry $a_{3,3}$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ and the only non-zero entry of that row. However, with the question as presented, we have no reason to expect the matrix of $f$ to be diagonal, in which case $a_{3,3}$ might not be an eigenvalue and the further left entries of the third row might be non-zero.

Comment: oh, i didn't mention, but f is indeed diagonalizable. I've got a couple of doubts though. As extending the B basis of W(dimW=3) to a B' basis in R^4 could be done by adding quite some many different possibilities of "w4" vectors, how can one be sure that there's not some other w4 vector possibility (thus, a different basis in R^4) for which f' is diagonalizable? (in the case that MB'(f) is not diagonal) Sorry if I'm not expressing myself correctly, but I've always learnt Math in Basque so this is a bit tricky!

Comment: @uberupense "Diagonalizable" and "diagonal" are different things. As a quick example, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1&0\\1&1&1&0\\1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&1}
$$
is diagonalizable, even though we added the Jordan block in the way that you prescribed. The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}
$$
is diagonalizable, but not diagonal.

Comment: Yeah, I know this. Okay now I get it, thanks a ton!!! Two quick questions though: I don't think I have seen that thing about (M−λI)^2 in my notes, so a name so that I can expand on it would be much appreciated. And secondly, going through the corrections of my teacher I saw one thing that bugs me. Imagine that the diagonal matrix of f has eigenvalue 1 located in a1,1. The new eigenvalue of the extended function appears to be 1 too, but instead of a Jordan block we see that a4,4=1 and a1,4=1. Why does he do that and is it related to my previous question? Thank you a lot, won't bother you more

Comment: I don't know of a common name for this fact about $(M - \lambda I)^2$.  I suspect that any linear algebra textbook that talks about Jordan canonical form also talks about this fact somewhere. Perhaps you can use the fact that elements of the nullspace of $(M - \lambda I)^2$ that are not elements of the nullspace of $(M - \lambda I)$ are called "generalized eigenvectors".

Comment: @uberupense As I say in my (now expanded) answer, when you set $a_{4,4} = \lambda$, the vector $v = (a_{1,4},a_{2,4},a_{3,4})$ needs to be set to something outside the range (which is also called the "column space") of $A - \lambda I$. For your diagonal $f$, $A - (1) I$ has a first row equal to $(0,0,0)$, so an easy way to pick something outside the range of $A - I$ is to set $a_{1,4}$ to be non-zero.